# How to convert a single number into a single item list in python

Tags: python, list, integer

My solution:

```
>>> i = 2
>>> list1 = []
>>> list1.append(i)
>>> list1
[2]
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: `list(i)` doesn't work. Does anyone know the reasoning behind this?

Answer (score 31):

This is just a special case:

```
list1 = []
```

You can put the lists contents between the brackets.  For example:

```
list1 = [i]
```

Answer (score 11):

```
mylist = [i]
```

This will create a list called mylist with exactly one element i. This can be extended to create a list with as many values as you want:
For example:

```
mylist = [i1,i2,i3,i4]
```

This creates a list with four element i1,i2,i3,i4 in that order. This is more efficient that appending each one of the elements to the list.

Answer (score 4):

To place something inside of a list, simply wrap it in brackets, like so:

```
i = 4
print( [i] )
```

or

```
iList = [i]
print( iList )
```

Run a working example here http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user39_XH1ahy3yu5b6iG0.py

Answer (score 1):

is it just a single assignment or is this within another construct?
if just an assignment:

```python
list1 = [2,] #This is equivalent to list1 = [2], I add the comma out of habit (but either works)
#if construct it depends but this assigns the variable as the list element
list1 = [i] #is fine
```

Comment: That trailing comma only works with tuples, like `(2,)`, and only because (2) would be considered an integer expression, not a tuple.  `[2,]` is a syntax error.

Comment: @MikeHousky try it, python 2 it works fine. Also just tested in Python 3 and it still works.

Comment: Odd.  I did try it (Python 2.7.8) and got the syntax error.  Trying again after your response, though, it worked!? Idle must have hiccuped.  I learned something today.  (Not sure I'll ever use it, though.)

Comment: yea, it is even more confusing when one switches between python, R, matlab from time to time.  it might be a good habit to always remember to add , to the single element whenever possible.

Comment: `tup1 = 2,` makes a single element tuple.  The () are optional.

Answer (score 0):

As it has already been said, you can write for a single value

```
    list1 = [i]
```

This is a "0th order" list comprehension which turns out to be a relevant and powerful python tool.

Check https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html