# How to place each element in a list as a list in another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I would like to have the output:

```
list2 = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]
```

I have tried looping over list 1 in various ways but am unsuccessful.

Comment: Ugh, this has to be a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a single number into a single item list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597831/how-to-convert-a-single-number-into-a-single-item-list-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
list2 = [[item] for item in list1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Also doable with `map()`:

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> list2 = list(map(lambda x: [x], list1))
>>> print(list2)
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
```