# New value at every iteration in Python

Tags: python, list

I want to get the updated values of `sigma1` at every iteration and I have `sigma[0] = 0.021`. But there is an error. I present the expected output.

```
sigma = []
for t in range(0, 3): 
    sigma[0] = 0.021
    sigma1 = sigma[t] - 0.001
print(sigma1)
```

The error is

```
 in <module>
    sigma[0] = 0.021

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

The expected output is

```
[0.021, 0.02, 0.019]
```

Comment: Empty list doesn't have 0-th element. You need to `append` some elements to a list to be able to access them.

Comment: Essentially the code is indexing into (being instructed to retrieve a value from) an *empty* list. Hence the index ‘out of range’ error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a single number into a single item list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597831/how-to-convert-a-single-number-into-a-single-item-list-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list is empty at first, so you can't get 0 index of it.

You probably want to set an initial value for you `sigma`:

```py
sigma=[0.021]
for t in range(2):
    sigma.append(sigma[t]-0.001)

print(sigma)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sigma=[0.021, 0, 0]
"""
if there are n element in the list
sigma=[0] * 5
sigma[0] = 0.021 

"""

#  iterate over the list from 1st index to 3rd index. 
for elem in range(1,3): # replace 3 with n is n numbers are there.
    # update the list with the previous element minus 0.001

    sigma[elem] = sigma[elem-1] -0.001

print(sigma)
```